# PHP Saving information to MySQL but not using hard coded code

Tags: php

My current code that saves to a MySQL database:

```
$q1 = $_POST["q1"];
$q2 = $_POST["q2"];
$q3 = $_POST["q3"];
$q4 = $_POST["q4"];
$q5 = $_POST["q5"];
$q6 = $_POST["q6"];
$q7 = $_POST["q7"];
$q8 = $_POST["q8"];


    $proc = mysqli_prepare($link, "INSERT INTO tresults_bh_main (respondent_id, ip, browser, q1, q2, q3, q4, q5, q6, q7, q8) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?);");
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($proc, "issiiiiiiii", $respondent_id, $ip, $browser, $q1, $q2, $q3, $q4, $q5, $q6, $q7, $q8);
```

At the moment this is all hard coded and I need it to use variables:

I have an array which stores the following information:

`$qs['questions']` - stores, for example q1, q2, q3, q4 etc - obviously these change both in terms of of numbers, ie. q10, q11, q12 and also the amount in the array - so there could be 4 q's or 10 q's stored in the array.

What I struggling to get my head around is how I would set-up this hard coded page to work with my array and variables, so I don't have to hand code the page.

Answer (score 0):

You need to normalise your database design.

You can keep your first table to record the response, but store a response_id as a unique, auto-incrementing primary key:

**tbl_responses**

```
response_id, respondent_id, ip, browser
```

Then add a second table to store the submitted data. A relationship is formed between the two tables on the response_id field. Create a composite key from both response_id and question_id to uniquely identify each row.

**tbl_questions**

```
response_id, question_id, value
```

Comment: I'm not sure how that answers my question?